# Evaluate integral $\int_{-2}^0 x^2+x\ dx$ using Riemann Sum

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

Consider the integral $$\int_{-2}^0 x^2+x\ dx.$$

The question says to use Riemann Sum theorem which is $$\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\delta x$$
I know that $\delta x= \frac{-2}{n}$ and that $x_i=-2+(\frac{2}{n}i)$

After i plug everything in I get $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2}{n}\left(-2-\frac{2}{n}i\right)^2+\left(-2-\frac{2}{n}i\right)$$

After completing the square I have $$\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}\left(4-\frac{8}{n}i\right)+\left(\frac{4}{n^2}i^2\right)+\left(-2-\frac{2}{n}i\right)$$

I know that $i=\left(\frac{(n+1)}{2}\right)$ and $i^2=\left(\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right)$ 
but how do I manipulate the equation so that I can use them?

Comment: $x_i = -2 + \left(\frac{2}{n} i\right) \;\Rightarrow.$

Comment: $x_i = -2 + \left(\frac{2}{n} i\right) \;\Rightarrow\; (x_i)^2 \;=\; 4 \;-\; \left(\frac{8}{n} i\right) \;+\; \left(\frac{4}{n^2} i^2\right).$

Comment: shouldn't $(xi)^2$ =4+ $(\frac{8}{n}i)+(\frac{4}{n^2}i^2)$

Comment: good question.  No, your formula for $x_i$ is wrong.

Comment: where does the $\frac{8}{n}i$ come from? wait I got it cause of the $2ab$ in $a^2+2ab+b^2$ right?

Comment: $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2.\;$  When $\;a=-2,\;$ and $\;b=\left(\frac{2}{n}i\right),\;$ then the middle term becomes $\;2\times (-2) \times \left(\frac{2}{n}i\right).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that $\delta x= \frac{-2}{n}$

The $\delta x$ should be positive. You should think of it as the length of the corresponding rectangle. In this case it is simplest to take $x_i=-\frac{2i}{n}$. So you have,

\begin{align*} 
&\int_{-2}^0 x^2+x\ dx\\ 
=&\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}
 \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\left(-\frac{2i}{n}\right)^2+\left(-\frac{2i}{n}\right)\right)\frac{2}{n}\\ 
=&\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}
 \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{8i^2}{n^3}-\frac{4i}{n^2}\right)\\
=&\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}
 \frac{8}{n^3}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i^2\right)
 -\frac{4}{n^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)\\
=&\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}
 \frac{8}{n^3}\left(
       \frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}\right)
 -\frac{4}{n^2}\left(\frac{1+n}{2}\right)\\
=&\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}
 \left(
       \frac{8}{3}+\frac{8}{2n}+\frac{n}{6n^2}\right)
 -\left(\frac{2}{n}+2\right)\\
=& \frac{8}{3}-2
\end{align*}

Comment: Didn't know you could write $i^2$ like that, it will be useful on my final. Thanks for you help>